# Add reaction to a specific message Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to create a command to add a reaction to a certain message.

The command is: `/react "Channel-ID" "Message-ID" "Emoji"`

But when running the command I get this error:

> (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid
> Form Body :channel_id: Value "845345565700128788
> <:XPLANE11:845383490286518322>" is not snowflake.

Is there any simple way of fixing this?

Thanks

```
client.on("message", message => {
        if (message.author.bot) return;
    
        let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
        let command = messageArray[0];
        let channelid = messageArray.slice(1);
        let messageid = messageArray.slice(2);
        let emoji = messageArray.slice(3);
    
        if (message.channel.type === "dm") return;
    
        if (!message.content.startsWith('/')) return;
    
           if (command === '/react') {
    
            let memberrole = message.member.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "CEO");
            if (!memberrole) return message.channel.send('Insufficiant Perms');
            
            message.client.channels.fetch(channelid.slice(1).join(" ")).then(channel => {
                channel.messages.fetch(messageid.slice(2).join(" ")).then(message => {
                    message.react(emoji.slice(3).join(" "));
                })
            })
          }});
```

For anyone wondering, this is the code that worked:

```
client.on('message', async (message) => {
    if (
      message.author.bot ||
      message.channel.type === 'dm' ||
      !message.content.startsWith(prefix)
    )
      return;
    
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);

    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  
    if (command === 'react') {

      const [channelId, messageId, emoji] = args;
  

      if (!channelId)
        return message.channel.send(`You need to provide a channel ID`);

      const memberrole = message.member.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === 'CEO');
      if (!memberrole) return message.channel.send('Insufficiant perms');
  
      try {
        const channel = await message.client.channels.fetch(channelId);
        if (!channel)
          return message.channel.send(`No channel found with the ID ${channelId}`);
  
        const msg = await channel.messages.fetch(messageId);
        if (!msg)
          return message.channel.send(`No message found with the ID ${messageId}`);
  
        msg.react(emoji);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        message.channel.send('Oh-oh, there was an error...');
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're using `Array#slice()` incorrectly. [`Array#slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array. When you use `messageArray.slice(1)` you actually create a new array by chopping off the first element of `messageArray`, the command. For `messageid` you're chopping off the first two elements of `messageArray`, leaving you the message ID and the emoji. Check out the snippet below. If you run it, you can see the values of each variables:

```js
const message = { content: '/react 845345565700128700 845345565700128788 <:XPLANE11:845383490286518322>' }
let messageArray = message.content.split(' ');
let command = messageArray[0];
let channelid = messageArray.slice(1);
let messageid = messageArray.slice(2);
let emoji = messageArray.slice(3);

console.log({ command, channelid, messageid, emoji })
```

So, at this moment, `channelid` is an array of three elements; the channel ID, the message ID, and the emoji. Inside the `channels.fetch()` method you once again create a new array by chopping off the first element and then `join` the rest by a single space. So, it becomes `845345565700128788 <:XPLANE11:845383490286518322>`. Check out the snippet below:

```js
// messageArray.slice(1);
const channelid = [
  '845345565700128700',
  '845345565700128788',
  '<:XPLANE11:845383490286518322>',
]

console.log(channelid.slice(1).join(' '))
```

If you check the value you try to fetch, it's exactly the one in your error message, `Value "845345565700128788 <:XPLANE11:845383490286518322>" is not snowflake`. It's not a valid snowflake. It's actually the message ID and the emoji in a single string.

To solve this, you could simply get the second element of the `messageArray` as the `channelid`, the third one as the `messageid`, etc:

```js
let messageArray = message.content.split(' ');
let command = messageArray[0];
let channelid = messageArray[1];
let messageid = messageArray[2];
let emoji = messageArray[3];
```

You could also use array destructuring to get the same:

```js
let messageArray = message.content.split(' ');
let [command, channelid, messageid, emoji] = messageArray;
```

And here is the full code:

```js
// use a prefix variable
const prefix = '/';

client.on('message', async (message) => {
  if (
    message.author.bot ||
    message.channel.type === 'dm' ||
    !message.content.startsWith(prefix)
  )
    return;

  // create an args variable that slices off the prefix and splits it into an array
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  // create a command variable by taking the first element in the array
  // and removing it from args
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === 'react') {
    // destructure args
    const [channelId, messageId, emoji] = args;

    // check if there is channelId, messageId, and emoji provided
    // if not, send an error message
    if (!channelId)
      return message.channel.send(`You need to provide a channel ID`);

    // same with messageId and emoji
    // ...

    const memberrole = message.member.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === 'CEO');
    if (!memberrole) return message.channel.send('Insufficiant perms');

    try {
      const channel = await message.client.channels.fetch(channelId);
      if (!channel)
        return message.channel.send(`No channel found with the ID ${channelId}`);

      const fetchedMessage = await channel.messages.fetch(messageId);
      if (!fetchedMessage)
        return message.channel.send(`No message found with the ID ${messageId}`);

      fetchedMessage.react(emoji);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      message.channel.send('Oh-oh, there was an error...');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much for your response, I really appreciate it. When I run the command I now get the error `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'message' before initialization.`

Comment: You're welcome. That's strange though, it should work. Could you copy-paste your code on a site like [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) and send me the link, so I could take a look?

Comment: https://srcb.in/FSrig6mSnn Here it is, I also get this message when starting the bot `(node:4) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 message listeners added to [Client]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit` But that does not crash the bot.

Comment: It looks like `client.on('message', async (message)` is inside your `client.on('ready', async () => {` listener.

Comment: I have edited my post and added the code that worked, thank you so much for your help! Its really appreciated.

Comment: Great, I'm glad I could help you. You don't need to edit your question with this code, you can accept this answer by clicking the checkmark (✓) next to it, this way others can see that it's working and also the explanation.

Comment: Thanks, could you please update your code to change the 

`const message = await channel.messages.fetch(messageId);
      if (!message)
        return message.channel.send('No message found with the ID ${messageId}');

      message.react(emoji);` 

to

`const msg = await channel.messages.fetch(messageId);
      if (!msg)
        return message.channel.send('No message found with the ID ${messageId}');

      msg.react(emoji);` 

As that was the issue :) (Change the string variable `message` to `msg`)

Comment: Ah, I absolutely missed that. Thanks for pointing it out, I've just updated my answer :)